# How to create Background-images Field in magento backend. And Change Background-images All pages

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

How To Create Custom Field Background-images in magento Backend.?
Set Background Directly in Only Change Images So set Directly 
in All page Backend Set background-images.

Comment: can you explain in details? background images used in forntend pages or any other pages?

Comment: thenks for replay

Comment: i have set Background images in frontend  only one Cilck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code i have set backgrounds all page:-

```
<?php
$article = Mage::getModel('imageuploader/upload')->load(['id']);
$image_collection = Mage::getModel('imageuploader/upload')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'));
foreach ($image_collection as $image):
$imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $image->getData('img');
endforeach;
?>
```

style sheet code:-

```
.wrapper {background-image: url(<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>)
```